# How to exempt a textbox from being field

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project using vb.net and I have 4 text boxes and 2 tabpages on my form.
I wrote my program in such a way that all 4 text boxes MUST be filled before I can go to tabpage2.

Here is my problem.
I need textbox1 to be empty and still be able go to tabpage2 even when textbox2, 3 and 4 MUST be filled

Here is my code

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
   For Each TextBox As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf TextBox Is TextBox Then
            If TextBox.Text.Equals(String.Empty) Then
                If e.TabPage Is TabPage2 Then
                    MsgBox("fill textbox")
                    e.Cancel = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Hi @Diepriye, if my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply add `And TextBox.Name <> TextBox1.Name` to your conditional check.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
   For Each TextBox As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf TextBox Is TextBox Then
            If TextBox.Text.Equals(String.Empty) And TextBox.Name <> TextBox1.Name Then
                If e.TabPage Is TabPage2 Then
                    MsgBox("fill textbox")
                    e.Cancel = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

By the way, you can shorten this code by directly declaring TextBox As TextBox, and not As Control:

```
    Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
   For Each TextBox As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Textbox)()

            If TextBox.Text.Equals(String.Empty) And TextBox.Name <> TextBox1.Name Then
                If e.TabPage Is TabPage2 Then
                    MsgBox("fill textbox")
                    e.Cancel = True
                End If

        End If
    Next
```